# simple "Up a directory" button in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, directory

a while ago i was using htaccess to display some files, and recently i started that project again and found i had somehow deleted the "go up a level" button back then.

Can anyone tell me what the code line in htaccess looks like to get this button back? Should be relatively simple but i just cant find it... heres what i got.

```
Options +Indexes

# DIRECTORY CUSTOMIZATION
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>

IndexOptions IgnoreCase FancyIndexing FoldersFirst NameWidth=* DescriptionWidth=* SuppressHTMLPreamble

# SET DISPLAY ORDER
IndexOrderDefault Descending Name

# SPECIFY HEADER FILE
HeaderName /partials/header.html

# SPECIFY FOOTER FILE
ReadmeName /partials/footer.html

# IGNORE THESE FILES, hide them in directory
IndexIgnore ..
IndexIgnore header.html footer.html icons
# IGNORE THESE FILES
IndexIgnore header.html footer.html favicon.ico .htaccess .ftpquota .DS_Store icons *.log *,v *,t .??* *~ *#

# DEFAULT ICON
DefaultIcon /icons/generic.gif

AddIcon /icons/dir.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^


AddIcon /icons/pdf.gif .txt .pdf

AddIcon /icons/back.png ..

</IfModule>

Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found the problem, it was simple, just not very observant when looking at the code. The line "IndexIgnore .." roughly in the middle.